# cuML package takes a long time to import in jupyterlab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, wsl-2, cuml

I am trying to import the following function into my jupyterlab workspace: `from cuml.manifold import TSNE`

Sometimes it loads in with no issues, but other times it takes ages (or an indefinite period of time - I stopped each attempt at about 5 minutes). I don't quite understand what is going wrong here.

For context, I should note that as this is a linux-only package I am using it on my windows machine by way of a conda environment in WSL2. Everything else in my code is running well, I just don't understand why this particular piece is not?

I have CUDA 12.4 installed with driver version 551.61.

I installed the package using conda, the nightly release version using the following command:

```
conda create --solver=libmamba -n rapids-24.04 -c rapidsai-nightly -c conda-forge -c nvidia  \
    rapids=24.04 python=3.10 cuda-version=12.2 \
    jupyterlab dash pytorch
```

Packages installed in environment:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                  2_kmp_llvm    conda-forge
anyio                     4.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               23.1.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0          py310h2372a71_4    conda-forge
arrow                     1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
asttokens                 2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
async-lru                 2.0.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
attrs                     23.2.0             pyh71513ae_0    conda-forge
aws-c-auth                0.7.16               h79b3bcb_6    conda-forge
aws-c-cal                 0.6.10               hb29e0c7_1    conda-forge
aws-c-common              0.9.13               hd590300_0    conda-forge
aws-c-compression         0.2.18               hecc5fa9_1    conda-forge
aws-c-event-stream        0.4.2                hf9b2f7b_4    conda-forge
aws-c-http                0.8.1                h5d7533a_5    conda-forge
aws-c-io                  0.14.5               h50678d4_1    conda-forge
aws-c-mqtt                0.10.2               hf479d2b_4    conda-forge
aws-c-s3                  0.5.2                h4ad9680_0    conda-forge
aws-c-sdkutils            0.1.15               hecc5fa9_1    conda-forge
aws-checksums             0.1.18               hecc5fa9_1    conda-forge
aws-crt-cpp               0.26.2               h19f5d62_7    conda-forge
aws-sdk-cpp               1.11.267             h5606698_1    conda-forge
babel                     2.14.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.12.3             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
bleach                    6.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
blinker                   1.7.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
bokeh                     3.3.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
brotli-python             1.1.0           py310hc6cd4ac_1    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                hd590300_5    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.27.0               hd590300_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2024.2.2             hbcca054_0    conda-forge
cached-property           1.5.2                hd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
cached_property           1.5.2              pyha770c72_1    conda-forge
cachetools                5.3.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2024.2.2        py310h06a4308_0
cffi                      1.16.0          py310h2fee648_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        3.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.1.7           unix_pyh707e725_0    conda-forge
cloudpickle               3.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
comm                      0.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
condacolab                0.1.9                    pypi_0    pypi
contourpy                 1.2.0           py310hd41b1e2_0    conda-forge
cuda-cccl_linux-64        12.2.140             ha770c72_0    conda-forge
cuda-crt-dev_linux-64     12.2.140             ha770c72_1    conda-forge
cuda-crt-tools            12.2.140             ha770c72_1    conda-forge
cuda-cudart               12.2.140             hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
cuda-cudart-dev           12.2.140             hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
cuda-cudart-dev_linux-64  12.2.140             h59595ed_0    conda-forge
cuda-cudart-static        12.2.140             hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
cuda-cudart-static_linux-64 12.2.140             h59595ed_0    conda-forge
cuda-cudart_linux-64      12.2.140             h59595ed_0    conda-forge
cuda-nvcc-dev_linux-64    12.2.140             ha770c72_1    conda-forge
cuda-nvcc-impl            12.2.140             hd3aeb46_1    conda-forge
cuda-nvcc-tools           12.2.140             hd3aeb46_1    conda-forge
cuda-nvrtc                12.2.140             hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
cuda-nvtx                 12.2.140             h59595ed_0    conda-forge
cuda-nvvm-dev_linux-64    12.2.140             ha770c72_1    conda-forge
cuda-nvvm-impl            12.2.140             h59595ed_1    conda-forge
cuda-nvvm-tools           12.2.140             h59595ed_1    conda-forge
cuda-profiler-api         12.2.140             ha770c72_0    conda-forge
cuda-python               12.3.0          py310h9f9f131_2    conda-forge
cuda-version              12.2                 he2b69de_2    conda-forge
cudf                      24.04.00a489    cuda12_py310_240304_ge60aad110e_489    rapidsai-nightly
cudnn                     8.8.0.121            h264754d_4    conda-forge
cuml                      24.04.00a34     cuda12_py310_240304_gb0ba34091_34    rapidsai-nightly
cupy                      13.0.0          py310h7aad9d2_3    conda-forge
cupy-core                 13.0.0          py310had4011e_3    conda-forge
cytoolz                   0.12.3          py310h2372a71_0    conda-forge
dash                      2.16.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dask                      2024.1.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dask-core                 2024.1.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dask-cuda                 24.04.00a11     py310_240304_g6be9df9_11    rapidsai-nightly
dask-cudf                 24.04.00a489    cuda12_py310_240304_ge60aad110e_489    rapidsai-nightly
dask-expr                 0.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.8.1           py310hc6cd4ac_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
distributed               2024.1.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dlpack                    0.5                  h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
exceptiongroup            1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
executing                 2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
fastrlock                 0.8.2           py310hc6cd4ac_2    conda-forge
filelock                  3.13.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
flask                     3.0.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
fmt                       10.2.1               h00ab1b0_0    conda-forge
fqdn                      1.5.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.12.1               h267a509_2    conda-forge
fsspec                    2024.2.0           pyhca7485f_0    conda-forge
gflags                    2.2.2             he1b5a44_1004    conda-forge
glog                      0.7.0                hed5481d_0    conda-forge
gmock                     1.14.0               ha770c72_1    conda-forge
gmp                       6.3.0                h59595ed_0    conda-forge
gmpy2                     2.1.2           py310h3ec546c_1    conda-forge
gtest                     1.14.0               h00ab1b0_1    conda-forge
h11                       0.14.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
h2                        4.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
hpack                     4.0.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
httpcore                  1.0.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
httpx                     0.27.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
hyperframe                6.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
icu                       73.2                 h59595ed_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.6                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        7.0.1              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        7.0.1                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib_resources       6.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.29.3             pyhd33586a_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.22.1             pyh707e725_0    conda-forge
isoduration               20.11.0            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
itsdangerous              2.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.19.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
joblib                    1.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
json5                     0.9.20             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonpointer               2.4             py310hff52083_3    conda-forge
jsonschema                4.21.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonschema-specifications 2023.12.1          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonschema-with-format-nongpl 4.21.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter-lsp               2.2.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            8.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.7.1           py310hff52083_0    conda-forge
jupyter_events            0.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_server            2.12.5             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_server_terminals  0.5.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                4.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         2.25.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
keyutils                  1.6.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.21.2               h659d440_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.16                 hb7c19ff_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.40                 h41732ed_0    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
libabseil                 20230802.1      cxx17_h59595ed_0    conda-forge
libarrow                  14.0.2           h17fe1ab_9_cpu    conda-forge
libarrow-acero            14.0.2           h59595ed_9_cpu    conda-forge
libarrow-dataset          14.0.2           h59595ed_9_cpu    conda-forge
libarrow-flight           14.0.2           hdc44a87_9_cpu    conda-forge
libarrow-flight-sql       14.0.2           hfbc7f12_9_cpu    conda-forge
libarrow-gandiva          14.0.2           h308e607_9_cpu    conda-forge
libarrow-substrait        14.0.2           hfbc7f12_9_cpu    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           21_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.1.0                hd590300_1    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.1.0                hd590300_1    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.1.0                hd590300_1    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           21_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libcrc32c                 1.1.2                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libcublas                 12.2.5.6             hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
libcublas-dev             12.2.5.6             hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
libcudf                   24.04.00a489    cuda12_240304_ge60aad110e_489    rapidsai-nightly
libcufft                  11.0.8.103           hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
libcufile                 1.7.2.10             hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
libcufile-dev             1.7.2.10             hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
libcuml                   24.04.00a34     cuda12_240304_gb0ba34091_34    rapidsai-nightly
libcumlprims              24.04.00a       cuda12_240304_gc4a7a87_9    rapidsai-nightly
libcurand                 10.3.3.141           hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
libcurand-dev             10.3.3.141           hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
libcurl                   8.5.0                hca28451_0    conda-forge
libcusolver               11.5.2.141           hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
libcusolver-dev           11.5.2.141           hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
libcusparse               12.1.2.141           hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
libcusparse-dev           12.1.2.141           hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.19                 hd590300_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 hd590300_2    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.12               hf998b51_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 13.2.0               h807b86a_5    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            13.2.0               h69a702a_5    conda-forge
libgfortran5              13.2.0               ha4646dd_5    conda-forge
libgoogle-cloud           2.17.0               h31df0ca_2    conda-forge
libgoogle-cloud-storage   2.17.0               hc7a4891_2    conda-forge
libgrpc                   1.60.1               h74775cd_0    conda-forge
libhwloc                  2.9.3           default_h554bfaf_1009    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 hd590300_2    conda-forge
libjpeg-turbo             3.0.0                hd590300_1    conda-forge
libkvikio                 24.04.00a       cuda12_240304_g787a6a3_18    rapidsai-nightly
liblapack                 3.9.0           21_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libllvm14                 14.0.6               hcd5def8_4    conda-forge
libllvm15                 15.0.7               hb3ce162_4    conda-forge
libmagma                  2.7.2                h173bb3b_2    conda-forge
libmagma_sparse           2.7.2                h173bb3b_2    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.58.0               h47da74e_1    conda-forge
libnl                     3.9.0                hd590300_0    conda-forge
libnsl                    2.0.1                hd590300_0    conda-forge
libnuma                   2.0.16               h0b41bf4_1    conda-forge
libnvjitlink              12.2.140             hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.26          pthreads_h413a1c8_0    conda-forge
libparquet                14.0.2           h352af49_9_cpu    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.43               h2797004_0    conda-forge
libprotobuf               4.25.1               hf27288f_2    conda-forge
libraft                   24.04.00a66     cuda12_240304_gad27a731_66    rapidsai-nightly
libraft-headers           24.04.00a66     cuda12_240304_gad27a731_66    rapidsai-nightly
libraft-headers-only      24.04.00a66     cuda12_240304_gad27a731_66    rapidsai-nightly
libre2-11                 2023.09.01           h7a70373_1    conda-forge
librmm                    24.04.00a32     cuda12_240304_gf132d4b0_32    rapidsai-nightly
libsodium                 1.0.18               h36c2ea0_1    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.45.1               h2797004_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.11.0               h0841786_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              13.2.0               h7e041cc_5    conda-forge
libthrift                 0.19.0               hb90f79a_1    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.6.0                ha9c0a0a_2    conda-forge
libtorch                  2.1.2           cuda120_h2aa5df7_301    conda-forge
libutf8proc               2.8.0                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.38.1               h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libuv                     1.46.0               hd590300_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.3.2                hd590300_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.15                 h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libxcrypt                 4.4.36               hd590300_1    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.12.5               h232c23b_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hd590300_5    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               17.0.6               h4dfa4b3_0    conda-forge
llvmlite                  0.42.0          py310h1b8f574_1    conda-forge
locket                    1.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
lz4                       4.3.3           py310h350c4a5_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.4                hcb278e6_0    conda-forge
magma                     2.7.2                h51420fd_2    conda-forge
markdown-it-py            3.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.5           py310h2372a71_0    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mdurl                     0.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mistune                   3.0.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2023.2.0         h84fe81f_50496    conda-forge
mpc                       1.3.1                hfe3b2da_0    conda-forge
mpfr                      4.2.1                h9458935_0    conda-forge
mpmath                    1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
msgpack-python            1.0.7           py310hd41b1e2_0    conda-forge
nbclient                  0.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert-core            7.16.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.9.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nccl                      2.20.3.1             h3a97aeb_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.4                  h59595ed_2    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
networkx                  3.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nodejs                    20.9.0               hb753e55_0    conda-forge
notebook-shim             0.2.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numba                     0.59.0          py310h7dc5dd1_1    conda-forge
numpy                     1.26.4          py310hb13e2d6_0    conda-forge
nvcomp                    3.0.6                h10b603f_0    conda-forge
nvtx                      0.2.10          py310h2372a71_0    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.5.2                h488ebb8_0    conda-forge
openssl                   3.2.1                hd590300_0    conda-forge
orc                       1.9.2                h7829240_1    conda-forge
overrides                 7.7.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
packaging                 23.2               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    2.2.1           py310hcc13569_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
partd                     1.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    10.2.0          py310h01dd4db_0    conda-forge
pip                       24.0               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
platformdirs              4.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
plotly                    5.19.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.20.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.42             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  4.25.1          py310h620c231_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.8           py310h2372a71_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h36c2ea0_1001    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyarrow                   14.0.2          py310hf9e7431_9_cpu    conda-forge
pyarrow-hotfix            0.6                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.17.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pylibraft                 24.04.00a66     cuda12_py310_240304_gad27a731_66    rapidsai-nightly
pynvjitlink               0.1.13          py310hf694660_0    rapidsai-nightly
pynvml                    11.4.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.7.1              pyha2e5f31_6    conda-forge
python                    3.10.13         hd12c33a_1_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-fastjsonschema     2.19.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-json-logger        2.0.7              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-tzdata             2024.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.10                    4_cp310    conda-forge
pytorch                   2.1.2           cuda120_py310h327d3bc_301    conda-forge
pytz                      2024.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    6.0.1           py310h2372a71_1    conda-forge
pyzmq                     25.1.2          py310h795f18f_0    conda-forge
raft-dask                 24.04.00a66     cuda12_py310_240304_gad27a731_66    rapidsai-nightly
rapids-dask-dependency    24.04.00a6                    0    rapidsai-nightly
rdma-core                 50.0                 hd3aeb46_0    conda-forge
re2                       2023.09.01           h7f4b329_1    conda-forge
readline                  8.2                  h8228510_1    conda-forge
referencing               0.33.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.31.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
retrying                  1.3.3                      py_2    conda-forge
rfc3339-validator         0.1.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rfc3986-validator         0.1.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
rich                      13.7.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rmm                       24.04.00a32     cuda12_py310_240304_gf132d4b0_32    rapidsai-nightly
rpds-py                   0.18.0          py310hcb5633a_0    conda-forge
s2n                       1.4.5                h06160fa_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.12.0          py310hb13e2d6_2    conda-forge
send2trash                1.8.2              pyh41d4057_0    conda-forge
setuptools                69.1.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sleef                     3.5.1                h9b69904_2    conda-forge
snappy                    1.1.10               h9fff704_0    conda-forge
sniffio                   1.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sortedcontainers          2.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
soupsieve                 2.5                pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
spdlog                    1.12.0               hd2e6256_2    conda-forge
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sympy                     1.12            pypyh9d50eac_103    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.11.0            h00ab1b0_1    conda-forge
tblib                     3.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tenacity                  8.2.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
terminado                 0.18.0             pyh0d859eb_0    conda-forge
tinycss2                  1.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.13          noxft_h4845f30_101    conda-forge
tomli                     2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
toolz                     0.12.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.4             py310h2372a71_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.14.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
treelite                  4.0.0           py310h4a6579d_0    conda-forge
types-python-dateutil     2.8.19.20240106    pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.10.0               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.10.0             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
typing_utils              0.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2024a                h0c530f3_0    conda-forge
ucx                       1.15.0               h6d2d1ec_3    conda-forge
ucx-proc                  1.0.0                       gpu    rapidsai-nightly
ucx-py                    0.37.00a12      py310_240304_g388c7af_12    rapidsai-nightly
uri-template              1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   2.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.13             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
webcolors                 1.13               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
websocket-client          1.7.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
werkzeug                  3.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.42.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.11               hd590300_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xyzservices               2023.10.1          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.5                h59595ed_1    conda-forge
zict                      3.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zipp                      3.17.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.13               hd590300_5    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.5                hfc55251_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about the cuML version, CUDA version, GPU model, and how you installed the software package (conda/pip)? If conda, can you share the output of `conda list`?

Comment: @BradleyDice updated the post with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted to reproduce this problem unsuccessfully. I created a fresh environment with cuML nightlies using

```
conda create --solver=libmamba -n rapids-24.04 -c rapidsai-nightly -c conda-forge -c nvidia  \
    cuml=24.04 python=3.10 cuda-version=12.0
```

I then ran `time python -c "import cuml"` 100 times. The first time took 52 seconds, and all subsequent times took less than 5 seconds, so I don't see the instability / variance that you observed.

Generally, importing RAPIDS libraries can take a bit longer than CPU-only libraries because of the time spent initializing CUDA and loading code on the GPU. I don't have a good explanation for why the first-time import took 52 seconds, but I was running this on a system with a slow network filesystem. I suspect that a good portion of that time was spent reading many small files from the network filesystem before they were cached for subsequent invocations.

If you have any further insights on this issue or come up with a way to reproduce the apparent hangs, that would be greatly appreciated in an issue: https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml/issues

Comment: Yeah, started everything with a fresh install (wsl2/envrionment and cuda included) and that seems to have repaied the importing error.

Thanks for your help with this.